# Why doesn't ctype_alpha recognize integers -128 to 255 as letters if they are part of an array?

Tags: php

Why do these return true:

`ctype_alpha(74); // returns true
$bar = 74;
ctype_alpha($bar); // returns true`

but this returns false:

`$foo = [1,2,3,'74'];
ctype_alpha($foo[3]); // returns false`

Comment: I believe from your example you read [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) already but take a look at the very bottom. Did you try setting the local information by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the numeric values in your test array, only 74 is the ASCII code of a letter (J), but you have supplied that as a string, not an integer, so it will not be interpreted as a character. The integers 128, 127, and 64, do not correspond to any letters, which is why `ctype_alpha` returns false for those. When you supply 74 as an integer value, then it does return true. `ctype_alpha` is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is explained why on php manual.

> **Note**: 
>   If an integer between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is
>   interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character (negative values
>   have 256 added in order to allow characters in the Extended ASCII
>   range). Any other integer is interpreted as a string containing the
>   decimal digits of the integer.

You may want to try with `ctype_digit($testcase)` to search for digits instead of search for alphabetic characters, or even better, to see if string is numerical: `is_numeric($testcase)`

I find that `is_numeric()` is most powerful as it doesn't give a damn if it is pure integer or numerical string. It looks for numbers only, and if numbers-only (floats should be counted in as well) are found, it returns true.

Comment: Thanks! Remember that is_numeric() recognizes exponential parts, "Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value" per the manual.  Can trip you up in certain cases if you're not aware of it.